# Mean Well Power supplies have much lower efficiency and much higher leakage current than rated

Tags: power-supply, efficiency, testing, specifications, leakage-current

I am going to have a power supply which will always be connected to AC mains and occasionally, a led strip will be connected and disconnected to the supply with a relay. I want an efficient and low "no Load" power supply. The two power supplies I've bought are below:

**1. Mean Well RS-25-12:** efficiency 81.5% | LEAKAGE CURRENT < 2mA / 240VAC (aka no Load power < 0.5W) | [RS-25 datasheet](https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/RS-25/RS-25-spec.pdf)

**2. Mean Well LRS-35-12:** efficiency 86% | LEAKAGE CURRENT < 0.75mA / 240VAC (aka no Load power < 0.2W) | [LRS-35 datasheet](https://octopart.com/datasheet/lrs-35-12-mean+well-61710290)

I made some tests with my UT89X multimeter when they arrived. I used different lengths of the same LED strip as loads when calculating Pout and Pin that's why output current differs but this is not important now. My results are below:

***Mean Well RS-25-12:***
Pin_noLoad = 224V * 0.034A = 7.62VA |
Pout_Loaded = 12V * 1.46A = 17.52W |
Pin_Loaded = 224V * 0.170 = 38.08VA |
eff = %46

***Mean Well LRS-35-12:***
Pin_noLoad = 224V * 0.046A = 10.3 |
Pout_Loaded = 12.08V * 1.21A = 14.6W |
Pin_Loaded = 224V * 0.245A = 54.88VA |
eff = %26.6

Terrible performance. Even a 2.2 dollars power supply outperform them, the result for the cheap power supply is below:

***CATA 60W:***
Pin_noLoad:  224V * 0.0082A = 1.84VA |
Pout_Loaded = 10V * 1A = 10W |
Pin_Loaded = 224V * 0.112A = 25VA |
eff = %40

The output voltage dropped from 12V to 10V as the cheap power supply is loaded but that's not the point.

I've used alternating and direct current and voltage settings on the mulltimeter as needed during my test. I didn't consider the power factor in my calculations as I didn't know the value but I think it will make the results only slightly better. Is my method of test wrong? Is Mean Well a very bad brand? Am I being sold fake brand power supplies even though the sellers are relatively trustworthy?

I bought each RS-25-12 and LRS-35-12 for 12.5 dollars.

**ENLIGHTENMENT EDIT (Solution):**
I assumed power factor would be a constant value around 0.8 ~ 0.9 But in reality it fluctuates between 0 and max value depending on the load. Thus my VA measurements doesn't mean anything on behalf of efficiency. Sorry Mean Well :D

Comment: A volt-meter and a ampere-meter won't help you defining active and reactive power. You need a watt-meter.

Comment: As far as I know, the input capacitor and flyback transformer inductance of the power supply takes some amount of charge from mains and gives some of them back 100 times a second. That's why the ampmeter counts some of the charge two times. But the results are way off from the rated. The power factor must be extremally small to make up for this. What point am I missing?

Comment: From where did you buy these then? And do you mistakenly think "Leakage Current" means "No load current" - it doesn't.

Comment: Those should be labeled S, not P. The power factor on these will generally be poor, about 0.5. Your measurements match with datasheet expectations.

Comment: In the datasheet it states both the leakage and no Load power, my test results are way higher than both. I bought RS-25 from https://www.direnc.net/ and LRS-35 from https://karakoyelektronik.com/ They are both Turkish part suppliers.

Comment: Okay let's consider power factor is 0.5 and my apparent power for LRS-35-12 is 10.3W This means True power = 10.3 * 0.5 = 5.15W which is still way above 0.2W that's stated in the datasheet.

Comment: You're not accounting for the power factor, so your measurements are not the real input power.  You need to measure the power factor, which is probably really low at idle.

Comment: The data sheet in note 1 states "All parameters NOT specially mentioned are measured at 230VAC input, rated load and 25 of ambient temperature." It sounds as if they might be measuring efficiency at full load (i.e. maximum output current). Efficiency may drop as you reduce the output current (DC to DC converters have this problem, perhaps your AC to DC converter has a similar issue). Try testing it at the full load current.

Comment: Can power factor be as low as 0.0194 at idle? Also I am not expecting %86 efficiency at low load ofc but %26 is too low. Anyway I started to realize my mistake, I guess I overestimated the power factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons for the gap between the datasheets and your expectations.

- "Leakage current" refers to leakage from L-E (primarily due to filter capacitors), not zero load supply current.
- Your measurements are giving you VA not power, and small supplies such as these often have very bad power factors at anything other than full rated load (unless they explicitly quote a PF nearer 0.98, in which case they have active PFC).

You need to use a watt meter to determine actual efficiency.

If you are not convinced, think about the heat from a 40W light bulb, and then decide if this is the amount of heat coming out of your LRS35 unit when you are quoting 26% efficiency (as the other 74% would have to be going as heat if your interpretation was right).

Comment: Shouldn't I just multiply the VA I measured with power factor and obtain true power? I must multiply 10.3VA with 0.0194 to get 0.2W no load power. Look at the datasheet of LRS35 it says no load power is lower than 0.2W So can the power factor of the supply be as low as 0.0194? Maybe the power factor is this low for no load case but increases with load.

Comment: Power factor of an unloaded switching supply could virtually be 0 (i.e. capacitive). As it approaches full load it will improve to its maximum value.

Comment: Okay I understood my mistake. Thank you. Now I have two supplies at the same price in my hand and I will refund one. I will run a 12V 1.5A led strip. I think LRS35 is better with its 0.3W less no load consumption and greater voltage range control (for dimming). But LRS35 will operate further from its maximum current which means it will have lesser efficiency than rated compared to RS-25. But I guess the difference will be small by also considering maximum efficiency of LRS35 is %4.5 higher already. Which supply should I keep?